# Update specific sql record using values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a bit of a trouble, writing a query string, to update a specific sql record.
I have all my respective values stores in strings, and whebn i add them (values as parameters), it will convert the primary id to an int. So far, so good.

The problem lies in my query string it self. I can do deleting and creation of sql records (select and insert) yet the problem here, lies in updating. That i have no real experience in.

Now... For the query string that i have all ready...

```
SqlCommand DerGemmesMedarbejder = new SqlCommand("UPDATE MyTableInQuestion VALUES (@Tittel, @FuldeNavn, @MailAdresse, @TelefonNummer, @MedarbejderType) WHERE PersonaleID = @PersonaleID_FraRepeateren", GemDetAendredeIndhold);
```

I just can not seem to get it right. The debugger is telling me that the problem is "incorrect syntax near jeyword 'VALUES'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax for update command is not valid. You may confused with Insert and Update command

Update command would be like this

```
UPDATE MyTableInQuestion set title=@Tittel, FuldeNavn=@FuldeNavn where PersonaleID = @PersonaleID_FraRepeateren
```

Comment: FuldeNavn=@FuldeNavn Should be TheStringNameIUse=@FuldeNavn ?

Comment: `@FuldeNavn` is the parameter which holds the value, which will used as a value of `FuldeNavn` column.

Comment: So. If i draw this "DerGemmesMedarbejder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tittel", Tittel_DerSkalGemmes);" from my strings that holds the values to be stored, then i should be ok with using "Tittle=@Tittle", as the values are drawn from my variables? (strings and an int)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
SqlCommand DerGemmesMedarbejder = new SqlCommand("UPDATE MyTableInQuestion set title=@Tittel, FuldeNavn=@FuldeNavn, ... WHERE PersonaleID = @PersonaleID_FraRepeateren", GemDetAendredeIndhold);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this query -

```
UPDATE MyTableInQuestion 
SET 
      Tittel = @Tittel
    , FuldeNavn = @FuldeNavn
    , MailAdresse = @MailAdresse
    , TelefonNummer = @TelefonNummer
    , MedarbejderType = @MedarbejderType
WHERE PersonaleID = @PersonaleID_FraRepeateren
```

Comment: Sorry... Forgot "Tittel" not "@Tittle" in Tittle=@Tittle.

Answer (score 0):

Because the syntax is incorrect.
Syntax [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

For update statements, you must change your query to this:

```
UPDATE MyTableInQuestion SET Column1 = @Tittel, Column2 = @FuldeNavn, Column3 = @MailAdresse, Column4 = @TelefonNummer, Column5 = @MedarbejderType WHERE PersonaleID = @PersonaleID_FraRepeateren"
```

Where Column1-5 is your column names